# Get name (not full path) of subdirectories in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, filesystems, subdirectory, python-os

There are many posts on Stack Overflow that explain how to list all the subdirectories in a directory. However, all of these answers allow one to get the *full path* of each subdirectory, instead of just the name of the subdirectory.

I have the following code. The problem is the variable `subDir[0]` outputs the full path of each subdirectory, instead of just the name of the subdirectory:

```
import os 


#Get directory where this script is located 
currentDirectory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


#Traverse all sub-directories. 
for subDir in os.walk(currentDirectory):
    #I know none of my subdirectories will have their own subfolders 
    if len(subDir[1]) == 0:
        print("Subdirectory name: " + subDir[0])
        print("Files in subdirectory: " + str(subDir[2]))
```

How can I just get the name of each subdirectory?

For example, instead of getting this:

> C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Programming\Image-Database\Curated\Hype

I would like this:

> Hype

Lastly, I still need to know the list of files in each subdirectory.

Comment: For the first part, split the `str` on `'\'` and take the last element. i.e. `sample_str.split('\')[-1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Splitting your sub-directory string on `'\'` should suffice. Note that `'\'` is an escape character so we have to repeat it to use an actual slash.

```
import os

#Get directory where this script is located
currentDirectory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

#Traverse all sub-directories.
for subDir in os.walk(currentDirectory):
    #I know none of my subdirectories will have their own subfolders
    if len(subDir[1]) == 0:
        print("Subdirectory name: " + subDir[0])
        print("Files in subdirectory: " + str(subDir[2]))
        print('Just the name of each subdirectory: {}'.format(subDir[0].split('\\')[-1]))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `os.path.basename`

```
for path, dirs, files in os.walk(currentDirectory):
    #I know none of my subdirectories will have their own subfolders 
    if len(dirs) == 0:
        print("Subdirectory name:", os.path.basename(path))
        print("Files in subdirectory:", ', '.join(files))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) coupled with [`os.path.isdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir) for this.

Enumerate all items in the directory you want and iterate through them while printing out the ones that are directories.

```
import os
current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
for dir in os.listdir(current_directory):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(current_directory, dir)):
        print(dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
dirList = os.listdir()
for directory in dirList:
    if os.path.isdir(directory):
        print('Directory Name: ', directory)
        print('File List: ', os.listdir(directory))
```